# Custom validation using helpers method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I want to make custom validation for Comment model: unregistered users shouldn't use e-mails of registered users, when they submitting comments.

I put custom validator class `app/validators/validate_comment_email.rb`:

```
class ValidateCommentEmail < ActiveModel::Validator

  def validate(record)
    user_emails = User.pluck(:email)
    if current_user.nil? && user_emails.include?(record.comment_author_email)
        record.errors[:comment_author_email] << 'This e-mail is used by existing user.'
    end
  end

end
```

And in my model file `app/models/comment.rb`:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with ValidateCommentEmail
  ...
end
```

The problem is that I use `current_user` method from my `sessions_helper.rb`:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

Validator can't see this method. I can include sessions_helper in Validator class, but it gives me an error about cookies method. It's a road to nowhere.
So how to make this custom validation rails way?

Comment: May a comment be associated with a user directly (besides for an author_email)?

Comment: I suppose by calling `current_user.nil?` you want to make sure that the user that is commenting is not registered. Isn't it possible to check whether the comment record has an associated user? That way you should not need `current_user`.

Comment: If comment submitted by existing user, it associated with a user directly. But I want to check that unregistered users don't use e-mails from registered users. So I need to check that this user: 1. not logged in; 2. his e-mail not in the array of registered e-mails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the comment knows if it was created by a registered user (`belongs_to :user`), you can simply check against that:

```
def validate(record)
  if record.user_id.nil? && User.where(:email => record.comment_author_email).exists?
    record.errors[:comment_author_email] << 'This e-mail is used by existing user.'
  end
end
```

If not, I think this validation should not be performed using a standard validator.  It won't be aware of enough of the context to determine if the model meets this criteria.  Instead, you should manually check this by passing the current_user from the controller itself:

```
# in comments_controller.rb
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  if @comment.validate_email(current_user) && @comment.save
   ...
end

# in comment.rb
def validate_email(current_user)
  if current_user.nil? && User.where(:email => record.comment_author_email).exists?
    errors[:comment_author_email] << 'This e-mail is used by existing user.'
  end
end
```

Comment: @AlexFedoseev: Note that you can more efficiently check for a matching email using `exists?` - see updated.